# ROS /clock not being published

Tags: python, python-3.x, ros, gazebo-simu

I'm having issues with ROS /clock not being published. I am running a simulation in Gazebo on Ubuntu 20.04. My code is getting stuck on a simple action client wait for server function.

To check if it was being sent anything, I rostopic echoed the client's topic and got this error: `WARNING: no messages received and simulated time is active. Is /clock being published?`. So I also echoed /clock and got the same error. I do not believe my simulation was paused, which is what I've seen as an explanation online. Any idea how to get the simulation clock to publish correctly?

Comment: Do you see /clock in rostopic list? Gazebo should publish the /clock topic for you.

Comment: Yes. And it was publishing when I ran rostopic echo /clock. I think I'm having issues with my internal clock because I got this to work now but I am having issues with catkin_make saying that files were created in the future.